# A residue computation occurring in HRR theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f(z)=\exp(mx)/(1-\exp(-x))^{n+1}$ defined and analytic in a punctured neighborhood of $0$. One knows, see for instance [here](https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/the-grothendieck-riemann-roch-theorem-a-proof-sketch/),  that the residue of $f$ at $0$ is the binomial coefficient $n+m$ choose $m$. Can someone sketch a proof of this computation or at least indicate the tools needed for this? The singularity is an essential one and I think it is relatively hard to deal with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(z) = \frac{e^{mz}}{(1-e^{-z})^{n+1}}=\frac{e^{(m+n+1)z}}{(e^{z}-1)^{n+1}} \tag{1}$$
and
$$ \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}f(z)\,dz \tag{2}$$
where $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve enclosing the origin. Since $z\mapsto e^z-1=z+O(z^2)$ is a conformal map, by the substitution $e^{z}-1=w$ we get:
$$ \text{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{(w+1)^{m+n}}{w^{n+1}}\,dw \tag{3}$$
which equals the coefficient of $w^{n}$ in the binomial expansion of $(w+1)^{m+n}$, i.e. $\binom{m+n}{n}=\binom{m+n}{m}$.

The proof of the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) exploits a similar trick.

Comment: Can you quote a reference for this "substitution rule" for complex path integrals?